# Xamarin forms PopupPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup

I'm using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages for popup page, when I press a button the popup appears in the middle of the page and I have a radiobuttons to select in it and when I finish, I touch on the transparent background to exit. My problem is that in the background page I have a label I need to modify according to what I chose in the popup page on the onAppearing method of the page, whenever I touch on the background of the popup page disappear and the onAppearing of the background page never get called!

The button is placed in the background page

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TestingClass.multiselection.Count; i++)
            {
                if (TestingClass.multiselection[i].is_selected)
                    btn.Text += TestingClass.multiselection[i].description;
            }
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

I'm getting the values from a static class when the popup is appeared the values are saved like this:

```
private void RadioButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var rb = sender as RadioButton;
            var selection = rb.BindingContext as multi_selection;
            if (selection != null && selection.is_selected == true)
            {
                selection.is_selected = false;
            }
            else
            if (selection != null && selection.is_selected == false)
            {
                selection.is_selected = true;
                TestingClass.multiselection.Add(selection);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both OnApperearing and OnDisappearing will not be get called when you add a popup in the view.

In [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear?language=objc),it says:

> viewWillAppear:
>
> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to
> be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured
> for showing the view.

In [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/#oncreate):

> OnCreate
>
> OnCreate is the first method to be called when an activity is created.

Adding a popup or removing a popup is neither create/remove a new view or add/remove the view to/from hierarchy. So, these lifecycle methods won't be called at that time.

**Solution:**

About how to set the button's text after selecting in popup, I agree with `Денис Чорный`'s answer, let me clarify it with code.

1.Use `eventHandle`:

In the popup page, define a `EventHandler`:

```
public EventHandler SelectedStringChanged { get; set; }
```

In your `RadioButton_Clicked`, add a line to call SelectedStringChanged:

```
    private void RadioButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var rb = sender as RadioButton;
        var selection = rb.BindingContext as multi_selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.is_selected == true)
        {
            selection.is_selected = false;
        }
        else
        if (selection != null && selection.is_selected == false)
        {
            selection.is_selected = true;
            TestingClass.multiselection.Add(selection);
        }

        //Add this line
        SelectedStringChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

In the background page, create a method to deal with btn.text:

```
    private void Handle_SelectedStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs rags)
    {
        // ... your code
        for (int i = 0; i < TestingClass.multiselection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (TestingClass.multiselection[i].is_selected)
                btn.Text += TestingClass.multiselection[i].description;
        }
    }
```

In the popup method,consume the `Handle_SelectedStringChanged` method:

```
    private async void OnOpenPupup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _loginPopup.SelectedStringChanged += Handle_SelectedStringChanged;

        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(_loginPopup);
    }
```

2. `MessageingCenter` will also work.

In the background page:

```
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "stringSelected", (sender) => {
          // do something whenever the "stringSelected" message is sent
            for (int i = 0; i<TestingClass.multiselection.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (TestingClass.multiselection[i].is_selected)
                    btn.Text += TestingClass.multiselection[i].description;
                }
        });
```

In you popup page:

```
  private void RadioButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var rb = sender as RadioButton;
        var selection = rb.BindingContext as multi_selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.is_selected == true)
        {
            selection.is_selected = false;
        }
        else
        if (selection != null && selection.is_selected == false)
        {
            selection.is_selected = true;
            TestingClass.multiselection.Add(selection);
        }

        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "stringSelected");

    }
```

Refer: [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing it (as I know):

1. You can create `EventHandler` in your `PopupPage` and subscribe it while initializing this `popupPage`:

   ```
   MyPopupPage popup = new MyPopupPage();
   // Subscribe event
   popup.Save += SaveEventHandlerArgs;
   Navigation.PushPopupAsync(popup);
   ```

   In your `popupPage` after selecting a value, call your eventHandler and pass value as argument. After that `SaveEventHandlerArgs` method would be called, where you can get your value and do with it what you want;

   [Examples of using events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)
2. You can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center). Examples are in the link.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the platform the `OnApperearing` might only be called once. Maybe you can turn it around and hook into the `OnDisappearing` of the popup page and use that to update your values?

Comment: I edited my question, your answer is half correct. I can update it but I can't show it instantly on my page, I need to do that every time the page appears

Comment: Did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?